# substitution for more simply and shorter way than switch - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

When i know that in variable is string 'numpad', how i can simple render component with same name ? I have components Numpad, UnitList, ShiftList, and i want to render them individually.  I am making callback in my child, and i send back type of component (string), which i want to render from my parent. Then i set my variable to numpad,unitList or shiftList and then i want to render this component. Is there any more simple way, than write switch ? With switch i can just -

```
switch(type){
   case 'numpad':
      <Numpad .../>
      break;
   case 'unitList':
     .....

}
```

but i am looking for something more simple and shorter.

for now i have -

```
 render(){
      return(
         <div>
             <Child update={this.renderSomeComponent.bind(this)} />
             {(() => {
                  switch (this.state.type) {
                       case "numpad":   return <Numpad ../>;
                       case "unitList": return <UnitList ../>;
                       case "shiftList":  return <ShiftList ../>;
                       case "sideList":  return <SideList ../>;
                       default:      return false;
                  }

             })()}
        </div>
   )
}

renderSomeComponent(type){
    this.setState({
            type: type
        })
}
```

In child's component i have method -

```
handleClick(){
        this.props.update(this.props.type);
    }
```

Comment: I think you should share more code about what you are trying to do. It is not that clear.

Comment: Ok, wait for it :D

Comment: Where do you set `this.state.type`?  In the child how do you use `rednerSomeComponent`?

Comment: I am sending to child type(numpad,unitList,shiftList,sideList), then in Child at event `onClick` i am making callBack and i am sending back `this.props.type`. `this.state.type` i set in parent.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to avoid `switch ... case`, you can use a javascript object to handle the mapping. In your example, it means create an object whose keys are the different values of your variable and the values are the expected output :

```
const map = {
  value1: output1,
  value2: output2,
  ...
}
```

The code you gave above could then be written as follow :

```
import React from "react";
import Numpad from "the-location-of-your-numpad-component";
import UnitList from "the-location-of-your-unitList-component";
...

const mapTypeToComponent = {
  numpad: Numpad,
  unitList: UnitList,
  ...
}

// In your component
render(){
  const { type } = this.state;
  const ComponentToShow = mapTypeToComponent[type];

  return(
    <div>
      <Child update={this.renderSomeComponent.bind(this)} />
      <ComponentToShow />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps